# WebRequest is being sent twice

Tags: vb.net, webrequest

I have a basic VB.net function, which has to run a HTTP request. Unfortunately the URL is called twice, which results in a 500 error on my webserver. Any ideas?

```
Request = WebRequest.Create("http://10.211.55.5:8088/api/?Value=Script1")
Dim Response As WebResponse = Request.GetResponse()
Dim dataStream As Stream = Response.GetResponseStream()
Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
Label3.Text = responseFromServer
reader.Close()
Response.Close()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Wrap all the objects here in [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement)s, then see if it persists.

Comment: If I try this; the problem still persits:

Comment: Using Response As WebResponse = Request.GetResponse()
    Dim dataStream As Stream = Response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    Label3.Text = responseFromServer
    reader.Close()
    Response.Close()
End Using

Comment: That is still not enough `using`s. Wrap `Request`, `Response`, `dataStream` and `reader`, and remove the `Close`s.

Comment: Should I wrap them all in one using? Or separately usings.

Comment: It [doesn't matter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement#behavior).

Comment: When I put them in Usings, I get ".. is not declared" for all of the variables...

Comment: It is likely that you are calling the code twice. Where do you call the code from?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I think you are right. The trigger of the function is FileSystemWatcher1_Changed. If I test a MsgBox, it will also display twice. Any idea what I have to do?

Comment: @JorisvanderZalm The FileSystemWatcher may raise the changed event many times, so perhaps if you could work out some way to use a StopWatch to avoid calling the code in the question too frequently then it would work as desired.